# How to resolve out of bounds error in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm getting an index out of bounds error from axis 0. The exact error is:

> index 319 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 319

Though I have tried other posts, every index out of bounds error seems to be very different.

Here is a description of the situation: we have a school project to do. We have to upload an image and modify it using different things we've learned over the past few weeks. I've already asked for help from the teacher but he doesn't understand it either.

I have a bunch of code to import the photo and then this bit to take out an outline that has a pretty consistent grey color and make it entirely transparent:

```
height = len(img)
width = len(img[0])
for row in range(0, 180):
    for column in range(0, 400):
        if sum(img[row][column]) >3<4:
            (img[row][column]) = [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

If more info is needed I can add that too.

It points to the line with the sum on it for the error but have no idea what is causing it and can change it to fix it.

Why is this error happening and how can it be fixed?

edit in response to  wibul and jecoms:__________________________________________

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

Z:\unit 1\1.4\1.4.7 1.py in ()

```
 21 for row in range(0, 180):

 22     for column in range(0, 400):
```

---> 23         if sum(img[row][column]) >3<4:

```
 24             (img[row][column]) = [1, 1, 1, 0]

 25
```

IndexError: index 319 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 319

I believe this is a full traceback, if not I apologize if don't understand what it is. again sorry, but whats a code block? it said add four spaces before a code block but, I don't understand. I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Arrays are zero based. An array of size 319 would have indices from 0-318. You have a lot of extraneous information in the question. Try and reduce it to the specific target of the error and post code in a code block (add four spaces before a code line).

Comment: can you include the full traceback for the error?

Comment: okay just posted it and can see in comments that it doesn't include indent ill retype in as an edit in the OG post.